# How can I deploy a streamlit application in repl.it?

Tags: python, replit, streamlit

I installed/imported `streamlit`, `numpy`, and `pandas` but I do not know how I can see the charts I have made. How do I deploy it on repl.it?

Answer (score 2):

You can not deploy streamlit application within repl.it because

> In order to protect against CSRF attacks, we send a cookie with each request.
> To do so, we must specify allowable origins, which places a restriction on
> cross-origin resource sharing.

One solution is push your code from repl.it to GitHub. Then deploy from GitHub on share.streamlit.io.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can.

1. Add the `streamlit` by going to *Packages*, searching for `streamlit`, and clicking on *install*

[[image: Add streamlit]]

2. Write your code (for example in a file called `app.py`)
3. Go to the *shell* of Repl.it and type `streamlit run app.py` (assuming your app is indeed called that way)
4. It might ask you if you want to register your email: either enter or press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
5. Wait a bit: a "Firefox" window will open in Repl.it with the app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: main.py to drive the streamlit app]

[image: your streamlit app code will be in here]

[image: finally, you can click Start button for the program to run]

First picture: your streamlit app code will be in here.

Second one: main.py to drive the streamlit app.

Last one: you can click Start button for the program to run.